# Sum values from JSON array response by PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am retrieving JSON data in array and I sort them into the HTML table. So far it is OK, but I would like to sum the specific values from JSON Response and print the sum of object values.

I have a PHP code which sorting me the data from JSON as following:

```
foreach($result->response as $value)
 {

  echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $value->datetime  . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $value->service_type  . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $value->destination  . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $value->duration  . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $value->price  . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

 }
```

I am interested only in values of prices (in JSON Array), I would like to take only the value of prices from JSON and sum the values of prices and give the result number under the table.

I am trying this without any success:

```
$countprice = $result->response->price;
$totalprice = count($countprice);
echo $totalprice;
```

The result is weird number, I know that PHP use "count", but I am not sure how to use it. Sorry I am novice in JSON and PHP and I will thank you for any tip you may give me.

Comment: You mean `SUM` of price?

Comment: Is `$result->response` a JSON ?

Comment: yes sorry for my English I will try to correct it:)

Comment: No it is mainly PHP problem, I am already handling the JSON response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
    <?php

    $sum = 0;
    foreach ($result->response as $value) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $value->datetime  . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $value->service_type  . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $value->destination  . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $value->duration  . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $value->price  . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    $sum += $value->price;
    }
    echo "sum is {$sum}";
```

Comment: You can add the sum control to the echo =)

Comment: Yes you can have also the echo lines let me update it

Comment: That is what I looked for. Your code is just simple and works on 100%. Thank you.